If Io were the size of Earth, what would its atmosphere consist of?

I am designing a volcanic Hell-like super-Io in my solar system and I want it to be like Io.
Io in real life is, of course, a moon of Jupiter. It has a mass of just 0.015 Earths and has a very thin, tenuous atmosphere. Io’s volcanism is fuelled by tidal heating from its eccentric orbit combined with a close proximity to Jupiter.
My planet has a mass similar to Earth’s and is volcanically active thanks to both an eccentric orbit (+ close proximity) around its star, along with lots of radiogenic heating (more than Earth). The surface of the planet is very similar to Io.
If Io were the size of Earth (and able to hold onto more than just a tenuous atmosphere), what would its atmosphere be like? Would it still primarily consist of sulphur dioxide?

There are planets (for example, Mars and Venus) that are fairly comparable in size to Earth but have wildly different atmospheres. There are a lot of contributing factors here and coming to a definitive answer will be very difficult. I would imagine that, yes, there would be a lot of $\mathrm{SO}_2$, but predicting anything beyond that would probably be far too much work for worldbuilding. Handwave a pseudo-plausible atmosphere and you're fine.

Could you fill us in regarding the other satellites and thus the orbit and temperature of Io? Much of the temperature on Io is as a result of tidal heating because of orbital resonances - these are in part sustained by the other moons - if it were Earth-sized, then that would be markedly different as the other moons would likely have been swallowed, the orbit of Io circularized and the temperature would be much lower. The temperature-drop would radically affect the likelihood of retaining an atmosphere. Can you fill us in on the missing details.

Is it still in the Jovian radiation belts?

I’d say the most important factor in determining the answer to this question is the geological composition of the planet. If its mantle is mostly made up of the same elements as Io’s, then it’s highly likely that yes, this world will mostly have a sulfur dioxide atmosphere (add salt to taste). However, another major factor is this world’s density. Io has a fairly high density in terms of its mass (3.2575 g/cm^3). If you make this world’s density uniform relative to its mass, it will have a much less tenuous atmosphere. However, it’d still be made up of the same gases.

Size alone is not sufficient to determine the atmospheric composition of a planet: size, and its related gravity well and escape velocity, determines only which gases the planet can retain on long term, as depicted in this never enough cited chart from Wikipedia

Other factors to keep into account:

the planet temperature: the higher the temperature, the higher the average speed of the gas molecules in the atmosphere and the higher the chance of them escaping the gravity well.
the planet geological history: according to the current understanding, Earth had an original atmosphere very different in composition from the current one, and also got most of its water some time after its formation, while its mass has not appreciably changed in the meantime.

All this to say that just by knowing the size we (and you) can at most rule out certain gases, but there is not enough information to pinpoint a unique composition. You have also to define the history of the planet.
